# Taking variance of some rows above in panel structrure (R data table )

Tags: r, datatable

```
# Example of a panel data
library(data.table)
panel<-data.table(expand.grid(Year=c(2017:2020),Individual=c("A","B","C")))
panel$value<-rnorm(nrow(panel),10) # The value I am interested in
```

I want to take the variance of prior two years `value` by `Individual`.
For example, if I were to sum the value of prior two years I would do something like:

```
panel[,sum_of_past_2_years:=shift(value)+shift(value, 2),Individual]
```

I thought this would work.

```
panel[,var(c(shift(value),shift(value, 2))),Individual]
# This doesn't work of course
```

Ideally the answer should look like

```
a<-c(NA,NA,var(panel$value[1:2]),var(panel$value[2:3]))
b<-c(NA,NA,var(panel$value[5:6]),var(panel$value[6:7]))
c<-c(NA,NA,var(panel$value[9:10]),var(panel$value[10:11]))
panel[,variance_past_2_years:=c(a,b,c)]
# NAs when there is no value for 2 prior years
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `frollapply` to perform rolling operation of every 2 values.

```
library(data.table)
panel[, var := frollapply(shift(value), 2, var), Individual]

#    Year Individual     value        var
# 1: 2017          A  9.416218         NA
# 2: 2018          A  8.424868         NA
# 3: 2019          A  8.743061 0.49138739
# 4: 2020          A  9.489386 0.05062333
# 5: 2017          B 10.102086         NA
# 6: 2018          B  8.674827         NA
# 7: 2019          B 10.708943 1.01853361
# 8: 2020          B 11.828768 2.06881272
# 9: 2017          C 10.124349         NA
#10: 2018          C  9.024261         NA
#11: 2019          C 10.677998 0.60509700
#12: 2020          C 10.397105 1.36742220
```